# Удобство написания BDD тестов Android Studio+Cucumber/Gherkin

Tags: android-studio, cucumber

Android проект в Android studio, написан на java.
В проекте есть  автоматические тесты - Espreso+Cucumber/Gherkin.
В коде имеются аннатации такого типа:

```
@Then ("check template")
  public void checkTemplate() {...}

@Given ("Template")
   public void getTemplate() {...}
```

и тесты используют BDD поход

```
...
Given Template
Then check template
...
```

Приходит в проект новый инженер и его задача писать тесты. Вот как увидеть сразу все доступные шаги ("Check Template", "Template") для тестов?
Поделитесь как вы решаете в своем проекте такую задачу.
У меня было две идеи:

1. Выгрузить просто всё аннотации по фильтру в док. В идеале при сборке проекта формируется такой док. Гуглила, ничего не нашла подобного. Возможно такой список можно получить из репорта Cucumber'а. Или взять отдельную библиотеку/плагин, которая например просто все аннатации в коде найдет по фильтру. Но не могу ничего подобного найти. Или вероятнее всего просто не совсем понимаю. Посоветуйте что-нибудь такое или хотя бы в какую сторону смотреть.
2. Еще возникла идея autocomplete. Но такой плагин только для Intellij Idea. Есть что-то такое для Android Studio? чтобы именно BDD тесты дополнял.

PS: Ctrl+Shift+F не видится мне удобным вариантом :)))

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а что конкретно не так? слишком длинно?